# Adding modules to nginx-light (Debian / dotdeb)

Tags: nginx, debian, apt, dotdeb

http://packages.debian.org/testing/nginx-light

http://packages.debian.org/testing/nginx-full

Can I add modules to nginx-light installation that would only be available in nginx-full
without recompiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to build nginx from sources with desired modules for binary and integrate it in Debian using nginx-common package

you **NEED** recompile nginx to add modules

Here is why : http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,123868,123868

Comment: Do you know any performanc benchmark on both packages?
I like to stick to the deb's because they are way easier to maintain..

Comment: the more modules you add to nginx, the more CPU it will use. nginx-light shloud be faster and more secure than nginx-full. And order of module inclusion when compiling matters. As suggested make your own binary compiling as wanted and integrate it with nginx-common. This allows you to choose an updated or latest version of nginx.

Comment: I decided to simply go with nginx-light because I don't even need all other modules from -full. Thanks for your advice I accepted your answer therefore